# I am looking for a system similar to Acronis but open-source

Tags: windows

So, we have Acronis in our business, but due to the price it becomes expensive, but if we take into account the solution he learns it becomes indispensable.

Because of this, I would like an indication from the masters of a web-based system, where you only have one basic client like Acronis does to perform the backups.

If the web system is unable to connect to the client, send an alert to me just as Acronis does, and also by default generate reports of space used, work done, etc. Most importantly, have a connection to AWS S3 or any other bucket system like Wasaby.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. Imagine people not knowing Acronis but might have the perfect match (you certainly do not mean Acronis TrueImage, do you? AFAIK, [Acronis is a company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronis), not a software).

Comment: Do you rally mean open source, or will gratis do?